# Full calendar integration in Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento2.2.2

I am trying to integrate the full calendar in **Magento 2.2.2** with event management extension(custom).

I have follows all steps as suggested But still, it is not working.

Please help me to execute the **Full-calendar**.

Comment: Full-calendar? FE or BE?

Comment: Sorry... I am not aware of FE or BE. Can you just give me some ideas about these?

Comment: Frontend(webstore) or Backend(admin) where you want to add a calendar? What is Full-calendar? Can you explain more about this will help.

Comment: At both side.      Full-calendar - JS extension (https://fullcalendar.io) please visit this site to know about the full calendar.

Comment: Ok, i will check your issue and get back to you update early as possible.